# Automatically Export CSV from Odoo

Tags: python, automation, odoo, export-to-csv

The aim is to automatically export a csv file to a location on the server using odoos automated actions.
Daily or everytime a record is created.

I have got the first steps ok so that it will fire an action everytime the records created.

To get here I am using Odoos automated actions

Settings > automation > automated actions

I have created a new action called Test

I have linked the Related Document Model to invoice(which is what i want to save to csv)

I have created a new server action called Export to CSV

Its at this stage that things start to fall apart know I cant figure out which action I should be using. I have been trying to use the Execute python code but I am unable to get anything to run it says the following are available, although I cannot figure out how to access any of it.

```
# Available locals:
#  - time, datetime, dateutil: Python libraries
#  - env: Odoo Environement
#  - model: Model of the record on which the action is triggered
#  - object: Record on which the action is triggered if there is one, otherwise None
#  - workflow: Workflow engine
#  - Warning: Warning Exception to use with raise
# To return an action, assign: action = {...}
```

I tried to

```
print object
```

Just to see if anything was there but it returned a 500 error

```
opcode PRINT_ITEM not allowed (u'print object')
```

I am hoping someone has run into this before and can point me in the right direction. I have minimal python knowlegde. Any Assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I would suggest you to write a custom module to handle csv export. You would have much more flexibility and "power", than just simply using automated actions. And you can reuse that module anywhere you want. Also you might need external libraries to handle actual transportation of files. There are three basic steps to implement exportation: parse the data in csv apropriate format, create csv file, move it to external location. If you use ssh protocol for transportation, I would suggest you to take a look at python paramiko library.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: No - we moved away from odoo